# regex validation from a to z with an exception of certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable like this

`var time = "12h 55m";`

I am only allowed to use `H,h,M,m` characters in the string. If i have something like this

`var time = "12hk 55m";`

then it should produce an error. how can I validate this using regex expression.'

looking for something like this

`if (stringToTest.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/))`

Comment: so `12m 55h` is also valid?

Comment: yep it is valid

Comment: How about `65h 097h`?

Comment: In that case `"12h 55m".match(/^\d{1,2}[hm]\s+\d{1,2}[hm]$/g)`

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja only one `h` or `m` allowed

Comment: @gurvinder372 is right [hm] will catch only one character i.e. either h or m

Comment: @gurvinder372 you should also add an `i` at the end `/gi`

Comment: Is Regex really a good tool for this?  Parsing this seems quite straightforward with a good old for loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
/^\d{1,2}[hm]\s+\d{1,2}[hm]$/i
```

It matches **2 digits** followed by either *h* or `m`, followed by **one or more space**, followed by **2 digits** followed by either *h* or *m*

Following will match

```
"12h 55m".match(/^\d{1,2}[hm]\s+\d{1,2}[hm]$/i)

"12m 55h".match(/^\d{1,2}[hm]\s+\d{1,2}[hm]$/i)

"2m 55h".match(/^\d{1,2}[hm]\s+\d{1,2}[hm]$/i)

"12m 5h".match(/^\d{1,2}[hm]\s+\d{1,2}[hm]$/i)
```

These will not

```
"122h 555m".match(/^\d{1,2}[hm]\s+\d{1,2}[hm]$/i)
```

Comment: hours can comes with 3 integers or 2

Comment: This matchees `12h 55h`. In the comments above, the OP says they are allowed to use only one h

Comment: @sachilaranawaka In that case replace {1,2} with {2,3}

Comment: /^\d{1,2}h\s+\d{1,2}m$/gi is probably better.

Comment: @jrook in that case it will be `"12h 55m".match(/^(\d{1,2}h\s+\d{1,2}m)|(\d{1,2}m\s+\d{1,2}h)$/g)`

Comment: the string generated dynamically so i don't know whether it contains 1 or 2 or 3 or numbers

Comment: @sachilaranawaka you need to put {1,3} 1 is for min bound and 3 is for max bound. You can change the regex appropriately

Comment: It should be `test` not `match`. No need of `g` flag when using anchors `^` and `$`.

Comment: @Tushar You are right, removed `g` flag. Yes, `test` will be more efficient since it will directly return true/false.

Answer (score 0):

The **reg** in regex stands for **regular** and your data seems to have a possibility to be irregular. I'd recommend to do the check differently but since you're looking for a regex solution:

`/^(\d{2,3}h\s+\d{1,2}m)|(\d{1,2}m\s+\d{2,3}h)$/gi`

This will match `h` and `m` in either order but will reject if either is in the string twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following regex `^\d{1,2}[hmHM]\s\d{1,2}[hmHM]`:

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `{1,2}` Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- `[hmHM]` matches a single character in the list hmHM (case sensitive)
- `\s` matches any whitespace character
- `\d{1,2}[hmHM]` as described above
- `\g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

See following snippet to test it:

```js
var regex = /^\d{1,2}[hmHM]\s\d{1,2}[hmHM]/g;

function check(par){
  console.log(par.value + " match: " + regex.test(par.value));
}
```

```html
Insert a text in the input <input type="text" id="test" value="" onchange="javascript:check(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer apparently satisfies the OP. But I noticed that in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487767/regex-validation-from-a-to-z-with-an-exception-of-certain-characters#comment74030664_43487767) the OP says that the character symbols should not be repeated. For example, `12h 12h` should be invalid but all answers match this. I don't think this can be done using only regex. So here is an alternative solution:

```js
function timeParser(timeStr) {
  var acChars = ['h', 'H', 'm', 'M'];
  if ((timeStr.match(/\s/g) || []).length !== 1) return false;
  var tokens = timeStr.split(' ');
  for (var token of tokens) {
    var rx = new RegExp("\\d{1,3}[" + acChars.join("") + "]", "g");
    if (!token.match(rx) ||
      token.match(rx).length !== 1 ||
      token !== token.match(rx)[0]) return false;
    var tc = token.charAt(token.length - 1);
    acChars.splice(acChars.indexOf(tc), 1);
  }
  return true;
}

var timearr = ["12h 12h", "1m1h 515M", "12hk 55m", "H 12m", "m 12H", "12H 11m", "00m 001h", "20M 1"];

for (var tim of timearr)
  console.log(timeParser(tim));
```

and `12h 12h` is not matched.